# Logging in streams with MDC

Tags: scala, log4j, akka-stream

I'm building a system based on Akka Streams and i want to log every step/flow in the stream and add an identifier to be able to follow elements passing through the stream in the log.

I can see that the log method in a stream takes an implicit **LoggingAdapter** and i found out that a **DiagnosticLoggingAdapter** can take a Map of MDC parameters.

My challenge is to figure out how to get a hold of a **DiagnosticLoggingAdapter**

I have tried i various ways to get a logger that can take MDC parameters, but i am missing something.

First i just used the Logger from scalalogging:

```
class testClass()(implicit system: ActorSystem, mat: ActorMaterializer, ext: ExecutionContext){

  val log = Logger(getClass)

  def doThisFlow: Flow[ElementIn, ElementOut, NotUsed] = Flow[ElementIn].mapAsync(1)(ei => {

        Source.single(ei)
          .log("Starting of the stream")
          .via(someFlow)
          .log("Handling some flow")
          .runWith(Sink.head)
  })
}
```

This works without the MDC parameters.

Then i tryed to add MDC parameters via scala logging as discribed  [here](https://github.com/lightbend/scala-logging#using-scala-logging)

```
class testClass()(implicit system: ActorSystem, mat: ActorMaterializer, ext: ExecutionContext){

  val logger = Logger.takingImplicit[MDCLoggerObject](this.getClass.getName)

  def doThisFlow: Flow[ElementIn, ElementOut, NotUsed] = Flow[ElementIn].mapAsync(1)(ei => {

    implicit val mDCLoggerObject: MDCLoggerObject = MDCLoggerObject("some value", ei.id, ei.name)

        logger.debug("Starting the stream")

        Source.single(ei)
          .log("Starting of the stream")
          .via(someFlow)
          .log("Handling some flow")
          .runWith(Sink.head)
  })
}
```

But that only added the MDC parameters to the explicit written log statements and not the the log statements written by the stream method log(). It makes sense as this approache uses a LoggerTakingImplicit object and not a LoggingAdapter.

Then i tried to get a LoggingAdapter, through the akka.event.Logging library inspired by whats described [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/logging.html):

```
class testClass()(implicit system: ActorSystem, mat: ActorMaterializer, ext: ExecutionContext){

  val logging = Logging.getLogger(system.eventStream, "whatever")

    def doThisFlow: Flow[ElementIn, ElementOut, NotUsed] = Flow[ElementIn].mapAsync(1)(ei => {

    Source.single(ei)
      .log("Starting of the stream")
      .via(someFlow)
      .log("Handling some flow")
      .runWith(Sink.head)
  })
}
```

Then suddenly the objects that passed through the flow was printed after the log message written in the log() method.

I would like to figure out how to get a [**DiagnosticLoggingAdapter**](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/event/DiagnosticLoggingAdapter.html) with the methods getMDC og clearMDC. 
Can anybody explain how to get a **DiagnosticLoggingAdapter** or why i can't make it work